# PIC32 UART Communication Wrong Characters

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I am fairly new to PIC32 and am attempting to set up a very basic UART transmission to my computer through a DB9 connector. I am using a PIC32MX440F256H as my testing board. I have gotten the data to transmit, but the characters do not appear the same in the serial monitor (Tera Term). My assumption is the baud rate is not right, but I have attempted different fixes to no avail. I would appreciate any possible help in fixing this. An example output is sending 'A' returns a 0 on TeraTerm , and other characters appear as seemingly random characters on the TeraTerm. The code is as follows:

Main.c

```
#include "xc.h"
#include "p32xxxx.h"
#include "MX440F256H.h"
#include "UART.h"



void led1_on() {
    LATGbits.LATG6 = 0; //LED1 pin HIGH
}

void led1_off() {
    LATGbits.LATG6 = 1; //LED1 pin LOW
}

void led2_on() {
    LATDbits.LATD1 = 0; //LED2 pin HIGH
}

void led2_off() {
    LATDbits.LATD1 = 1; //LED2 pin LOW
}

void delay() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 250000; i += 1);
}

int main() {
    UART_Start();
    TRISDbits.TRISD1 = 0;
    TRISGbits.TRISG6 = 0;   //Setting LED pins to output
    
    while (1) {
        delay();
        led1_off();
        led2_on();
        delay();
        led1_on();
        led2_off();
        UART_Send("a",1);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

MX440F256H.c

```
#include "MX440F256H.h"

#pragma config FWDTEN   = OFF    // Turn off watchdog timer
#pragma config FNOSC    = FRCPLL // Select 8 MHz internal Fast RC (FRC) oscillator with PLL
#pragma config FPLLIDIV = DIV_2  // Divide PLL input (FRC) to get into required range 4MHz
#pragma config FPLLMUL  = MUL_20 // PLL Multiplier
#pragma config FPLLODIV = DIV_1  // PLL Output Divider
#pragma config FPBDIV   = DIV_2  // Peripheral Clock divisor
// 8/2*20/1/1= 80 MHz
```

UART.c

````
#include "xc.h"
#include "p32xxxx.h"
#include "MX440F256H.h"

int sysClk = 80000000;
int pbClk;
char test;

void UART_Start(){
    pbClk = sysClk/2;
    U1MODE = 0;
    U1STA = 0;
    
    U1BRG = pbClk/(16*115200)-1;
    
    U1STAbits.URXEN = 1;
    U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;
    U1MODEbits.PDSEL = 0; 
    U1MODEbits.STSEL = 0;
    U1MODEbits.ON = 1;
    U1MODEbits.BRGH = 0;
    U1MODEbits.ABAUD = 0;
  
}

void UART_Send(const unsigned char *data, unsigned int nBytes)
{
    unsigned int i;
 
    for(i = 0;i < nBytes;i++)
    {
        while(U1STAbits.UTXBF);
        U1TXREG = data[i];
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Define what you Tx,Rx’d . How are sharing SMPS or Earth grounds or floating?

Comment: I apologize, but I am not following. I am only using Tx, no Rx. If you're asking about the physical connection I have a ground pin from the MCU connected to the DB9 connector, then Tx of the MCU to Rx of DB9. The DB9 is then plugged into the computer via USB.

Comment: What do you have between MCU and the DB9 connector? Assuming the MCU does not talk RS232 levels and the DB9 serial port does, do you have a RS232 level translator, or are you simply feeding 3.3V logic levels into DB9 connector?

Comment: I meant what are you transmitting and receiving at the other end.  Try different patterns and data rates on each side. Is there a pattern? Have you scope signals yet? If not try 9600 1 N . You can also split the signal into 2 monitors on short cables depending on speed

Comment: Is that a `0` digit or a capital `O` letter you're receiving? is it's a capital `O` letter then @Justme has your answer for you. A lower-case `a` transmitted with its bits inverted through a UART (which is what happens what you connect logic levels to an RS232 receiver) is almost certain to come out looking like a capital `O`.

Comment: We assume you aren’t using RS-232 which is inverted data and bipolar.

Comment: DB9 is often used for RS-232, what is the part number and/or link to the USB to serial adapter?

Comment: The TXD is connected to the RXD of a PL2303 Cable. When sending a lowercase "a" I am getting back an Uppercase O.

Comment: PL2303 isn't specific enough, we need an exact part number or full specification. A DB9 connector will probably use RS-232. You probably don't want to use RS-232 unless you are transmitting a long distance and have an RS-232 to TTL converter on both ends. Get a plain USB to TTL serial adapter. If you have one like this, it won't work properly, logic zero is positive, logic 1 is negative, it may marginally accept zero volts as a logic 1, but your bits will be inverted! https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Prolific-Chipset-CableCreation-Converter/dp/B0758B6MK6

Comment: The cable is a CableCreation 6.6ft PL2303 USB to RS232 cable with a female DB9 end. Basically identical to what Mattman944 linked.

Comment: I am now understanding. Basically, there is no way to go direct UART to RS232 and expect to get anything expected on the other end. Would there be an IC (thinking MAX232) I could use to do this conversion so I can connect to RS-232? A device I am eventually attempting to connect to uses RS-232.

Comment: Connecting it to an FTDI breakout board I had fixed the issue! Thank you all very much for the help.